# Issue, mustache.js render multiple times the same template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm trying to render a mustache template (details.mustache) from JS. However the output of mustache.to_html show the same template with data multiple times. The example:

```
function onViewSectionSuccess(param){

  var template = $('#section_detail_template').html();
  var hashDetail = {
    'first' :[{'id' : param.data.id},{'description':param.data.description},{'title':param.data.title},{'icon':param.data.icon},{'created':param.data.created},{'updated':param.data.updated},{'native':param.data.native}]
    };
  var html = Mustache.to_html(template,hashDetail);
      $('#section_detail_view').html(html);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you call the function which renders the template?

Comment: What does your template html contain?